# Executing Create Trigger throws sometimes an error depending on the query-structure including a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have three TSQL-statements, each are supposed to create a trigger when executed.

I get only a partly parameterised statement to run.
What i dont understand is, why SSMS is executing the one statement and throwing an error with the two others. Any help is much appreciated.

1. This does NOT work: executing the statement without any variable

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = 'TR' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'D365_del' AND [name] = 'trg_Table_del') 
BEGIN
    CREATE TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del] ON  [D365].[Table] AFTER DELETE AS INSERT INTO [D365_del].[Table] ([ID], [Action],[ModifiedDate])(SELECT [ID], 1,SYSDATETIME() from DELETED)
END
```

2. This works: putting part of it into a variable

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

set @SQL = 'CREATE TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del] ON  [D365].[Table] AFTER DELETE AS INSERT INTO [D365_del].[Table] ([ID], [Action],[ModifiedDate])(SELECT [ID], 1,SYSDATETIME() from DELETED) '

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = 'TR' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'D365_del' AND [name] = 'trg_Table_del') 
BEGIN
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

3. This does not work: putting all of the statement into a variable

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

set @SQL = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = ''TR'' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = ''D365_del'' AND [name] = ''trg_Table_del'') BEGIN CREATE TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del] ON  [D365].[Table] AFTER DELETE AS INSERT INTO [D365_del].[Table] ([ID], [Action],[ModifiedDate])(SELECT [ID], 1,SYSDATETIME() from DELETED) END'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

In both cases where it doesn't work i get the same error-message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
```

I am using:

- SQL Server Management Studio  15.0.18424.0
- Windows Operating System      10.0.22000
- SQL-Server                    12.0.2000.8

Comment: Try wrapping your trigger body in BEGIN...END statement. Like so CREATE TRIGGER ... AS BEGIN ... END

Comment: From [`CREATE TRIGGER` - Trigger Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#trigger-limitations): "CREATE TRIGGER must be the **first statement in the batch** and can apply to only one table."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TRIGGER` must be the only statement in the batch. To address the problem:

option 1: Add a conditional `DROP` followed by a `GO` batch separator and `CREATE TRIGGER`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = 'TR' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'D365_del' AND [name] = 'trg_Table_del') 
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del].
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del] ON  [D365].[Table] 
AFTER DELETE AS
INSERT INTO [D365_del].[Table] ([ID], [Action],[ModifiedDate])
(SELECT [ID], 1,SYSDATETIME() from DELETED)
GO
```

option 2: Use `CREATE OR ALTER`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [D365].[trg_Table_del] ON  [D365].[Table] 
AFTER DELETE AS
INSERT INTO [D365_del].[Table] ([ID], [Action],[ModifiedDate])
(SELECT [ID], 1,SYSDATETIME() from DELETED)
GO
```

option 3 (which you've already discovered): Use dynamic SQL so `CREATE TRIGGER` is in a separate batch.